# How can create a function to get a json data and create a css grid with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css

[image]

(The top image is not the original design it is only an example which I wanna create it)

I wanna create a function to get an array of objects and create a div grid (NO TABLE) with this data. I wanna do this with css grid and pure javascript; I create below function but it doesn't work true; How can I create this function?

```
const createGrid (data){
const sidebarContent = document.querySelector('.sidebar-content');

for (const item of data) {

    const partNumberCell = document.createElement('div');
    partNumberCell.innerHTML = item.orderInfo.partNumber;
    sidebarContent.append(partNumberCell);
    const typeCell = document.createElement('div');
    typeCell.innerHTML = item.orderInfo.type;
    sidebarContent.typeCell;
    const timeCell = document.createElement('div');
    timeCell.innerHTML = 'test';
    sidebarContent.timeCell;
    const neededCell = document.createElement('div');
    neededCell.append((document.createElement('span').innerHTML = item.delayInfo.delayInSeconds));
    sidebarContent.append(neededCell);
    const statusCell = document.createElement('div');
    statusCell.append((document.createElement('span').innerHTML = item.statusInfo.status));
    sidebarContent.statusCell;

}
}
```

my json file get me an array of object like below object:

```
{
        "id": "a7c041f3-b53c-43e0-b9bd-5add831ced17",
        "orderInfo": {
            "partNumber": "",
            "type": "EMPTY",
            "origin": "SU-H38L1",
            "destination": "41A01L-T1",
            "demandTime": "2021-04-13T19:47:19.605343Z",
            "externalOrderId": "726273419",
            "containerType": "VW0001",
            "received": "2021-04-13T19:42:20.549696Z",
            "trailerPosition": null
        },
        "statusInfo": {
            "status": "RECEIVED"
        },
        "jobInfo": {
            "agvId": null,
            "agvExternalId": null,
            "agvJobId": null,
            "agvJobStatus": null,
            "startPlanned": null,
            "pickupPlanned": null,
            "dropoffPlanned": null
        },
        "delayInfo": {
            "delayInSeconds": 72168
        },
        "loadedInfo": {
            "pickupActual": null
        }
    },
```

Comment: Your data is in a json file ?

Comment: Yes it is a json file and the top image is only an example it is not my design. @Sou

Comment: JSON data can be structured any way you want. Your function depends on the structure of your data. i.e. you may want a JSON object called `headers` or instead, you may want each column as an object, with its own objected called headers. See? It depends on how you structure your JSON object.

Comment: Your question is about how to read the json file or about how to design the table in this way using a div grid?

Comment: @BrianScramlin look at this object my json file is an array of the object like below ```javascript      {
        "id": "a7c041f3-b53c-43e0-b9bd-5add831ced17",
        "orderInfo": {
            "partNumber": "",
            "type": "EMPTY",
            "origin": "SU-H38L1",
            "destination": "41A01L-T1",
            "externalOrderId": "726273419",
            "containerType": "VW0001",
        },
        "statusInfo": {
            "status": "RECEIVED"
        },

        "delayInfo": {
            "delayInSeconds": 72168
        },
       
    },   ```

Comment: Please update the question with the example object. This is hard to read as a comment and not everyone follows the whole discussion.

Comment: Thanks! What is this last line trying to do? `sidebarContent.statusCell;`. Shouldn't you append the cell to the sidebar content? That's a mistake or a syntax I'm not familiar with.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Oh my god :|||| That was exactly my code's bug :||| thank you very much it got correct :)))